# Can PTAS $\epsilon$ parameter be dependent on the algorithm input?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, approximation, polynomial-time

Let A be a PTAS algorithm with time complexity $O\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$.
Let $n$ be the input of the algorithm A.

From Wikipedia:

> The running time of a PTAS is required to be polynomial in $n$ for every fixed $\epsilon$, but can be different for different $\epsilon$.

Can we define $\epsilon$ to be equal to $\frac{1}{n}$?
Thus, the time complexity of A would be $O(n)$, which is polynomial in $n$, but, can $\epsilon$ be dependent on $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an algorithm whose running time is $O(1/\epsilon)$, then if you substitute $\epsilon = 1/n$, its running time will be $O(n)$. This is a property of the particular algorithm $A$ rather than of polynomial time approximation schemes. We have absolutely no guarantee on the running time of a PTAS when $\epsilon$ is subconstant (i.e., when $\epsilon = o(1)$).

The running time of algorithms tends to depend on the input length (though it's not always the case), so I'm not convinced that $A$ really has running time $O(1/\epsilon)$.

Comment: You are right, the actual running time of A is $O\left(n \cdot \frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$. The running time is still polynomial in n. That is, regarding the particular algorithm A, setting $\epsilon$ to be $\frac{1}{n}$ should not be a problem?

Comment: If $f(n,\epsilon) = n/\epsilon$ then $f(n,1/n) = n^2$.